# Async table creation and query advantages / disadvantages

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

In my application I have the following:

```
db2.CreateTable<CategoryGroup>();
db2.CreateTable<Category>();
db2.CreateTable<CategoryGroupSource>();
db2.CreateTable<CategorySource>();
db2.CreateTable<Phrase>();
db2.CreateTable<PhraseSource>();
db2.CreateTable<Score>();
db2.CreateTable<Setting>();
```

From what I understand there is an Async way to do this also:

```
database.CreateTableAsync<TodoItem>().Wait();
```

Can someone explain if there is any advantage in me using the Async way and do people normally always use the Async?

Also are there likely to be benefits if I use this type of Async query:

```
    public Task<TodoItem> GetItemAsync(int id)
    {
        return database.Table<TodoItem>().Where(i => i.ID == id).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
    }
```

Comment: Please try to research the topic a bit before asking questions. I would suggest to start reading from here about async in c#: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh191443(vs.110).aspx

Comment: CreateTableAsync will let the UI thread working, while using CreateTable won't.  Depending on the moment you execute your code (on start, after user interaction, you will need to use Async or not).

Comment: Your answer hugorgor is misleading in this example since the question has `.Wait();` after the async method which blocks the UI thread again.

Comment: @hamalaiv didn't see the .Wait() but it has no sense to put a .Wait()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When calling the methods on the main (UI) thread everything on the UI stops for as long as it takes that method to execute. If `db2.CreateTable<CategoryGroup>()` doesn't take up much time when doing it's thing, it shouldn't be a problem.

Doing a lot of time consuming actions straight after each other might affect your UI and make it freeze.

Calling the `*Async` variant of the method moves the work to a background thread, via the task API. Calling `Wait()` on that task, though, makes the current thread (in this case the UI thread) wait for the task to finish, and you're stuck with the same problem.

You should always `await` tasks: `await database.CreateTableAsync<TodoItem>()`. This will let it execute on a background thread **and** not make the current thread wait for it to finish. The next line in your code won't be executed until the Task is finished though. When you write the code, it makes the `*Async* variant *look like* it's behaving like the regular version.

Personally, I'd probably move all the methods into a task and just await that. That way you're not returning to the UI thread between each task to execute the next one:

```
await Task.Run(() =>
{
    db2.CreateTable<CategoryGroup>();
    db2.CreateTable<Category>();
    db2.CreateTable<CategoryGroupSource>();
    db2.CreateTable<CategorySource>();
    db2.CreateTable<Phrase>();
    db2.CreateTable<PhraseSource>();
    db2.CreateTable<Score>();
    db2.CreateTable<Setting>();
}
```

---

In this case you're making the database do all it's work on a background thread (and not freezing the UI while it's doing it). It then returns the result to the UI thread to enable you to update UI.

```
public Task<TodoItem> GetItemAsync(int id)
{
    return database.Table<TodoItem>().Where(i => i.ID == id).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
}
```